# SDL simple threading produces segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cygwin, sdl, mingw-w64

I've been trying to use SDL threading, but I've not been able to make it work properly. Even the simplest programs cause a segmentation fault.

I'm using mingw64 (not mingw32) inside the cygwin environment.
This code produces a segmentation fault both when run inside cygwin and outside it:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_thread.h>

int threadFunction(void* data) {
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    int dataIn=0;
    int dataOut=0;
    SDL_Thread* thread;
    SDL_Window* window;

    SDL_Init(0);
    thread=SDL_CreateThread(&threadFunction,"Thread",&dataIn);
    SDL_WaitThread(thread,&dataOut);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

However, once printf statements are added in between, like so:

```
SDL_Init(0);
printf("#1 ");
thread=SDL_CreateThread(&threadFunction,"Thread",&dataIn);
printf("#2 ");
SDL_WaitThread(thread,&dataOut);
printf("#3 ");
SDL_Quit();
printf("#4 ");
return 0;
```

Something very strange happens. When this code is run inside the cygwin environment, either with or without the `-mwindows` option, it works ok. The program exits normally. When this same code is run *outside* the cygwin environment it crashes *only* without the `-mwindows` option. Rearranging the printf's around has diverse results, sometimes making it crash and sometimes not.

When this code is run, the output is this:

```
Cygwin:  ./test -> #1 #2 #3 #4 
Windows: test   -> #1 (program freezes and a "test.exe has stopped working" window appears)
```

The compilation command I'm using is this: `gcc -I./SDL2 -o test test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` where gcc is a symlink to the x86_64 version of the mingw64 C compiler. I've also tried with the normal x86 (i386, 32-bits) version of mingw64/SDL and the same thing happens.

When compiling with the `-g` option and using `gdb` on the first example (without printf's) this is shown:

```
Starting program: /Test/test
[New Thread 5828.0x1084]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000006c868e30 in ?? () from /Test/SDL2.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x000000006c868e30 in ?? () from /Test/SDL2.dll
#1  0x000000006c830d29 in SDL_LogCritical ()
   from /Test/SDL2.dll
#2  0x000000006c7cb85f in SDL_LogCritical ()
   from /Test/SDL2.dll
#3  0x0000000000401600 in SDL_main (argc=1, argv=0x2f0010) at test.c:17
#4  0x0000000000402cfa in console_main ()
#5  0x0000000000402db1 in WinMain ()
#6  0x00000000004013e8 in __tmainCRTStartup ()
    at /usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-4.0.6-1/crt/crtexe.c:332
#7  0x000000000040151b in mainCRTStartup ()
    at /usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-4.0.6-1/crt/crtexe.c:212
```

Whereas the printf version:

```
Starting program: /home/Mimi/Escocia/C/Test/test
[New Thread 3380.0x98c]
[New Thread 3380.0x1a80]
[Thread 3380.0x1a80 exited with code 0]
#1 #2 #3 #4 [Inferior 1 (process 3380) exited normally]
```

(But running this program outside cygwin produces a segfault)

Is linking with libmingw32 on mingw64 wrong? (It doesn't seem right either, but it didn't compile without it.) Am I missing something obvious? Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Is it a bug? (If it is, where should I report it to: SDL, mingw64 or Cygwin?)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** After recompiling SDL the problem is gone. Does anyone know why does it work now? Are there any disadvantages to compiling it myself?

Comment: 1. `printf` don't flush if threre is no `\n`, message may be buffered for quite a time before displaying; it doesn't mean code didn't execute. 2. what is at `test.c:17` in your backtrace? There shouldn't be any `SDL_LogCritical` here. If possible, compile debug SDL library and link with it. Also `console_main` (static) function was renamed/removed [19 months ago](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/diff/2e624f24d1af/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c) - can you check with more recent SDL, preferably latest?

Comment: @keltar 1. I know. In fact, cygwin seems to be buffering all output until the program ends. I tried it with newlines and the same happened, so I changed it to spaces for prettier printing. I guess I should've put that in the question... 2. It's the creation of the thread. IDK why it's producing LogCriticals, but that's probably why printfs affect the output. Actually, I just checked and cygwin provides SDL 2.0.1 and the SDL extra modules 2.0.0! I'll try with the newest version. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried it. Using the newest version does not work. I compiled SDL with debug information enabled (for which I had to disable D3D rendering, I miss some libraries) and it magically worked. So I recompiled without -g and now I use that instead. Why does it work now? Is it some calling convention or something? Is there any downside to compiling it myself? Anyways, many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of mingw64 or cygwin is pretty much non-existent, and I cannot reproduce the issue on my mingw32 or linux machines (and I don't really think it is mingw-related). If printf affect behaviour - it looks much more like race condition, but after a quick look at `SDL_CreateThread` internals I see nothing suspicious (and `SDL_LogCritical` never called here, but it may have changed). Using self-compiled SDL is fine, but you might want to enable some optimisation too (`-O2` for gcc). Although I would've been worried if I had to ship software that only works with specific SDL build.